# I am using opencv in android studio to detect face in an image and want to display the detected image in ImageView. But its not working

Tags: java, android, opencv

```
CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml").getPath());
        CascadeClassifier eyeDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_eye.xml").getPath());

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(FaceDetector.class.getResource("bradpit.JPG").getPath());

        Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);


        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();

        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);


        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    new Scalar(0, 255, 0),2);
        }


        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Mat tmp = new Mat (100, 100, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
        try {

            Imgproc.cvtColor(image, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
        }
        catch (CvException e){
            Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());}



        int width = bmp.getWidth();
        int height = bmp.getHeight();
        ImageView img;
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: means its not showing any thing on my app. just a blank ImageView :(

Comment: I'd suggest taking opencv out of the equation, and first just see if you can get an android bitmap to display.  Then print out some debug info about the Mat and bitmap you're trying to display, like its height and width.